# Angular 2: Binding with JS without Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, binding

I'm using last available public version (beta17) and I can't understand why a simple binding (convert by fly) doesn't work there.
What's the problem with the plnkr?
http://plnkr.co/edit/PfAUb5hOvgTcn0vbOdG1

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/bootstrap4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.css' type="text/css"/>
  <!-- Angular libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/Rx.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
  <!-- Angular app modules -->
  <script src='app/app.js'></script>
  <script src="app/components/converter/converter.js"></script>
</head>

<body align='center'>
  <h1>Temperature Converter using Angular 2</h1>
  <converter class='converter'></converter>
</body>

</html>
```

**/app/app.js**

```
'use strict';

(function (app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.ConverterComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**/app/components/converter/converter.js**

```
(function (app) {
  app.ConverterComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'converter',
      templateUrl: '/app/components/converter/template.html'
      })
    .Class({
      constructor: function () {
        this.temperature = '';

        let temp = this.temperature;

        temp = parseInt(temp, 10);
        this.fahrenheit = ((9 / 5) * temp) + 32;
        this.kelvin = (temp + 273.15);
      }
    })

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**/app/components/converter/template.html**

```
<div class="box">

  <div>
      <label for="temp">Enter your temperature (ºC):</label>
      <br>
      <input id="temp" [(ngModel)]="temperature" class="textfield">
  </div>

  <div [hidden]="temperature">
    Waiting for your temperature...
  </div>

  <div [hidden]="!temperature">
    <h3>{{fahrenheit}} ºF</h3>
    <h3>{{kelvin}} K</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your all the URL's to be started without `/` like `app/app.js` instead of `/app/app.js`

Here is [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfAUb5hOvgTcn0vbOdG1?p=preview)

> **Note:** I would suggest you to use Angular 2 Final version instead of using old version

Comment: Me too. But right now there's no public files instead of npm.
And it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ValSaven what do you mean?

Comment: Here https://code.angularjs.org/ the last version is beta17. And after changing url names binding still doesn't work.

Comment: @ValSaven have you checked plunkr attached in answer?

Comment: Sure. But now it always give NaN

Comment: Got it. I just added (keyup)="setTime()" to the input in template.html and made setTime: function () in converter.js http://plnkr.co/edit/PfAUb5hOvgTcn0vbOdG1
p.s. But I have no idea how to use final version this way.